# Setting ImageView ScaleType to "center" is not working as I expect it

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

I have the following layout for my `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    (...)
</LinearLayout>
```

Those `48dp` equal to 36px, 48px and 72px in `ldpi`, `mdpi` and `hdpi` respectively. All the images that will be used in this `ImageView` are basically icons and I've found on the web what I want for my app (free license). But unfortunately, it doesn't come with images bigger than 48px and using different images is out of the question. So I need a new solution...

For now I have 36px and 48px images in the `ldpi` and `mdpi` folders, respectively. But I'm having trouble with `hdpi`. What I want for devices running on `hdpi` is for them to use the `mdpi` image (the bigger one available) and use it as it is, without scaling. Basically, the `ImageView` for `hdpi` is 72px, so I want the 48px image to be inside the 72px, in the center, without scaling. For that, I simply tried to change `scaleType` in the `ImageView` above to just `center`, but the image gets scaled anyway.

**My ultimate question in here is, what's the proper way to fix the problem described above? How can I have `ldpi` and `mdpi` images being used in their respective densities, but have devices running `hdpi` pick up the biggest image available (which is the `mdpi` ones) and prevent any scaling, just fitting the image in the center of the `ImageView`?**

**EDIT:**
I answered this question myself, but it might to be the answer others coming here are looking for. But I do provide some insight on what's really happening and the underlying problem. Please take a look and provide a workaround/fix if you can. I dare you :)

Comment: Yes, tried most logical possibilities. Nothing worked :(

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Generally people want than on a normal screen, five 64dp icons should always occupy whole screen width (which is 320dp), should always look the same no matter what device resolution, including that icons sides always touch (with optional device-independent padding)

Comment: I don't understand your question...

Comment: I was using a library to do it withdrawable(to make the background round) for my project work but as i changed it to ImageView it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question turns out to be a non-question and I apologize to anyone that founds it, hoping the accepted answer will be what they are looking for when it won't be.

To make it clear, `scaleType=centerInside` is working as expected. That is, if you have an image smaller than the `ImageView` itself, than that image won't be scaled to the bounds of the `ImageView`, it will remain in the center and unscaled.

But for the above to work as expected, the drawable must be placed in the `nodpi` folder. I understand that this is not always acceptable. So, when that drawable must be placed into one of the density folders instead of the `nodpi` folder, the `scaleType` attribute will only work in specific situations.

**When it will work:**

- You are running the app on a device/emulator with `Xdpi` density and
  there is a drawable in the `Xdpi` density folder (here `X` means,
  `l`, `m`, `h` or even `xh`).
- You are running the app device/emulator,
  for instance, with `hdpi` density, but there isn't a drawable in the
  `hdpi` folder and the system picks the alternative drawable from the
  `nodpi` folder (it's not always known which folder it will pick
  from).

**When it will not work:**

- You are running the app device/emulator, for instance, with `hdpi`
  density, but there isn't a drawable in the `hdpi` folder and the
  system picks the alternative drawable from any other of the density
  folders (not the `nodpi` folder), the drawable will be scaled to the
  `ImageView` bounds and the `scaleType` attribute will not do
  anything.

In conclusion, there's no "right" answer to my question, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. The answer *my* question though, I just need to do 2 things: a) Set the `ImageView` `scaleType` to `centerInside` and b) Duplicate all drawables from the `mdpi` folder into the `hdpi` folder (as explained above, the `scaleType=centerInside` will make it work).

Of course, duplicating drawables is not optimal, but I can't find any other solution and so far, no one else could either... So, in the time being, I'll mark this one as accepted.

**What would be the optimal answer/solution then?**
In my opinion, if the device/emulator is running in `hdpi` and there isn't a matching drawable in the `hdpi` folder it should be pick the drawable from the `mdpi` folder without scaling it, allowing the `scaleType` attribute to do it's thing. Or maybe force the system to go to the `nodpi` folder if it doesn't find a matching drawable in the respective density folder, that could a solution too.

So, if anyone can ever provide a workaround/fix to this issue, that would be the real correct answer. If it ever comes to that, I'll change the accepted status.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was setting the image as `android:background`. when I set it as `android:src`, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Here is where the money is -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving it out of the hdpi folder, and place it in a drawable-nodpi folder. I'm not sure what the hierarchy is (whether the nodpi would then override the ldpi and mdpi folders) but that would be my first try.

Comment: I never had anything in the `hdpi` folder. I only have 48px images in the `mdpi` folder and 36px images in the `ldpi` folder. I believe the image being picked up by `hdpi` devices is the ones in the `mdpi` folder. The problem is that the image is being scaled, when it shouldn't because I explicitly told it not to (`scaleType = center`).

Comment: Try it with the 48px image in the nodpi folder.

Comment: If I create a copy of all 48px images from the `mdpi` folder into the `nodpi` folder, it still doesn't work. I don't know from which folder the image being used in the `hdpi` device is picked up, but it still scales to the `ImageView` size. Neither `scaleType=center` or `scaleType=centerInside` are working, when they both should.

Comment: Hmm...well a bad solution would be to add android:anydensity="false" into your manifest, under `<supports-screens>`. You'd then have to manage any necessary scaling yourself. Are the images large enough that duplicating the mdpi images into the hdpi folder would be a problem?

Comment: Now I tried to **move** all 48px images to the `nodpi` folder, meaning both the `hdpi` and `mdpi` folders are empty and the `ldpi` folder has the 36px images. With `scaleType=centerInside`, `hdpi` devices work fine, but on `mdpi` devices, it seems the smaller images (from the `ldpi` folder) are being used and the image gets scaled. I seriously don't understand what's going on...

Comment: Yes, they are large enough and too many to have duplicates and handle the scaling manually. It's not the solution I'm after. There must be something I'm doing wrong, this should work...

Comment: Hmm, I've been looking through the documentation, and it SHOULD be picking the image from mdpi rather than scaling up the ldpi image, the way you had it originally, but obviously it isn't. Unfortunately I don't really have any other suggestions at this point, other than to copy the mdpi images into the hdpi folder. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: After testing this issue extensively I came up with a conclusion and insight on the real problem. Please take a look at my answer if you want and comment if you have anything to add or know the real answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:maxWidth="48px"
    android:maxHeight="48px"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="..."
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And put the images normally in the ldpi/mdpi folders.

Although I do not recommend using pixel values.

Comment: That's not what I want. I need the `ImageView` to have 72px (the equivalent for 48dp on `hdpi`) but I simply don't want the image to be scaled to fit that size if it happens to be smaller (that's what the `scaleType=center` is supposed to do). That's the problem here, I don't want fixed sizes.

Comment: Then wrap the ImageView inside `<FrameLayout android:layout_width="48dp" android:layout_height="48dp">`. How often do you need this? I dont think ImageView is designed to partially work density-independently ldpi-mdpi, and partially not in hdpi.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with a full example of that last suggestion please?

Comment: Edited. Although doing this for all icons is a little too much.

Comment: Not what I as expecting, you are still forcing the images to be no bigger than 48px and I don't want that. I want them to be 48px if they really are 48px, but if they are smaller, I want them smaller, if they are bigger I want them bigger (but not bigger than 48dp, 72px in hdpi). Maybe I'm not explaining myself correctly, but I'm not sure how to do it better. For the record, I also tried a similar example to the FrameLayout idea but without the 'max' parameters, the image still got scaled to the full size of the FrameLayout.

Comment: Well than copy the images from mdpi to hdpi, so they will be the same, and just use the simple ImageView

Comment: After testing this issue extensively I came up with a conclusion and insight on the real problem. Please take a look at my answer if you want and comment if you have anything to add or know the real answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom ImageView:

```
package x;

public class MaxMDPIImageView extends ImageView {

    public MaxMDPIImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        if (density>1) {
            canvas.translate(getWidth()/2-getWidth()/density/2, getHeight()/2-getHeight()/density/2);
            canvas.scale(1/density, 1/density);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Use it simply as:

```
<x.MaxMDPIImageView
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    />
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, I think you still don't understand what I'm trying to do. That code (again if I understand it correctly) will change **every** image size and I don't want that. Either way, this question is not relevant anymore, ready my long answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
```