# ScaleType center in Android appears to scale image

Tags: android

My device has a screen resolution of 600 x 800. I created a bitmap 600 x 600 and display it in an ImageView where ScaleType is set to "center". I also have my activity set to take up the entire screen. When the image is displayed, the image shows its correction ratio but appears larger than it should. The width appears larger with the edges cut off. According to the Android docs, setting the ScaleType to "center" is not suppose to cause any scaling. So why doesn't the image fit my width exactly?

Comment: Where is your bitmap located in your project? Also, what is the density of your device?

Comment: It's a png file located under drawable-hdpi. The device has a 233 dpi resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813460/3752244).

You seem to have fallen in the **When it will not work** scenario described there.